# How to parse the date and time depends upon the time zone?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, timezone

I want to parse the string to time.

```
string inputDate = "1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000"; 
var dt = DateTime.Parse(inputDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  
Console.WriteLine("Date==> " + dt);
```

It is working fine in india time(`UTC +5.30`).

But when I change the time zone to `UTC -5` in settings in emulator, the out put is showing

```
12/31/1969 7:00:00 PM
```

The date should be same when ever i change the time zone in settings. Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain what is going on here..

*Usually*, [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method returned `DateTime`'s [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) property will be [`Unspecified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx).

But since your string has time zone information and you using `DateTime.Parse` method without [`DateTimeStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) overload (it uses `DateTimeStyles.None` by default), your `DateTime`'s `Kind` property will be `Local`.

That's why when you use your code in `UTC +05.30` time zone system, it will be generate a result like;

```
01/01/1970 05:00:00 AM
```

and when you use in `UTC -05.00` time zone system, it will generate;

```
12/31/1969 7:00:00 PM // which is equal 12/31/1969 19:00:00 AM representation
```

which is too normal.

> The date should be same when ever i change the time zone in settings.

Makind your `DateTime` as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the best choice in such a case. Using [`ToUniversalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) method is one way to do that in a `Local` time.

From documentation;

> The Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is equal to the local time minus
>   the UTC offset.

Since your code generates `Local` time, your `ToUniversalTime()` generated datetime's will be the same in both time zone.

Another way to do it, using `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` as a third parameter in `DateTime.Parse` method.

From documentation;

> Date and time are returned as a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). **If
>   the input string denotes a local time, through a time zone specifier
>   or AssumeLocal, the date and time are converted from the local time to
>   UTC**. If the input string denotes a UTC time, through a time zone
>   specifier or AssumeUniversal, no conversion occurs. If the input
>   string does not denote a local or UTC time, no conversion occurs and
>   the resulting Kind property is Unspecified.

```
string inputDate = "1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(inputDate,
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

That will generate `01/01/1970 00:00:00` which `Kind` is `Utc`.

Comment: Super..!! Explanation is gr8.. Thanks for the explanation. This should be the answer for this question..!!

Answer (score 1):

Final Solution

```
string givenDate = ("1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000");
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(givenDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string ouputDate = d.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:m:s tt",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```